# How can I alter a table definition in Cassandra using only DBeaver?

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

I am currently working on a Cassandra (CQL) database and I use a DBeaver as graphical client.

How can I do alter a table and insert data into that table using only DBeaver?

Answer (score 0):

you must write sql command syntax(CQL Cassandra) for your Cassandra's key-space by -> [in menu] SQL Editor -> New SQL Editor -> write command's ALTER :

> ALTER (TABLE | COLUMNFAMILY) "tablename" "instruction"

then click "Execute Statement" above tab SQL code